# Time difference in function with similar logic

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing scripts to test sql-server DB. Trying to do that in optimal way and toying with sqlite.
Code snippet is just comparison of DB query to pre-determined value doing that in two different approaches but similar logic,
a) tcount() function
b) newcount() and test_test() function

I could not figure out why this time taken difference happens in code. Or this is too less to be ignored?

```
import sqlite3
import sys, time, re, timeit
import pytest

def timing(f):
    def wrap(*args):
        time1 = time.time()
        ret = f(*args)
        time2 = time.time()
        print 'Function :%s  took %0.3f ms' % (f.func_name, (time2-time1)*1000.0)
        return ret
    return wrap

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'E:\Python_Projects\Demo\sqlite-DBS\newdb.db')

@timing
def tcount():
    table_list = ['Album', 'Artist', 'Employee', 'Genre', 'Invoice', 'InvoiceLine', 'MediaType', 'Playlist']
    count_query = """select count(*) from %s;"""
    count = {'Album': 347, 'Playlist': 18, 'Artist': 275, 'MediaType': 5, 'Genre': 25, 'Invoice': 412, 'InvoiceLine': 2240, 'Employee': 8}
    table_count = {}
    for table in table_list:
        try:
            result = conn.execute(count_query % table)        
            for x in result:
                table_count[table] = x[0]
        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            print e
    return (table_count == count)

@timing
def newcount():
    table_list = ['Album', 'Artist', 'Employee', 'Genre', 'Invoice', 'InvoiceLine', 'MediaType', 'Playlist']
    count_query = """select count(*) from %s;"""

    table_count = {}
    for table in table_list:
        try:
            result = conn.execute(count_query % table)        
            for x in result:
                table_count[table] = x[0]
        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            print e
    return table_count

@timing
def test_test():
    count = {'Album': 347, 'Playlist': 18, 'Artist': 275, 'MediaType': 5, 'Genre': 25, 'Invoice': 412, 'InvoiceLine': 2240, 'Employee': 8}
    return (newcount() == count)


print tcount()
print test_test()
conn.close()
```

output:

```
Function :tcount  took 0.000 ms
True
Function :newcount  took 0.000 ms
Function :test_test  took 16.000 ms
True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should propably use the `timeit` module (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html) since it is far better in benchmarking than `time`.

But I think every SQL Command has some `info` command that can be called after the actual execution and prints the status of that code and how long it took to execute - which will be even more accurate than the timeit.

But since I haven't used sql in a long time I can't give you more information on that.

Comment: Thanks for response,No query returns table name and record count in table. I want them to be compared between staging and final. So, I'm using dict.

Comment: I am not familiar reading through how to do it. I will post updates once done.

Comment: If you use IPython or Jupyter you can skip all the messy setups and call `%timeit tcount()` or `%timeit test_test()` after importing these functions.

Comment: Unfortunately no.. I just use VIM with python standard edition :(